# Java - Implicit typecast for own Object

Tags: java, casting

I wrote an own class for fractions with the constructor like this:

```
class Rational {
    //A Class representing Rationals
    long numerator ;
    long denominator;
    Rational (long numerator , long denominator) {
        this.numerator = numerator ;
        this.denominator = denominator;
        if (this.denominator < 0) {
            this.numerator *= (-1);
            this.denominator *= (-1);
        }
    }

    Rational (Rational rational) {
        this.numerator = rational.numerator ;
        this.denominator = rational.denominator;
        if (this.denominator < 0) {
            this.numerator *= (-1);
            this.denominator *= (-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to (for example) multiply a fraction with an integer. Is there a way to make an implicite typecast from integer to fractional, so that the numerator equals the given integer and the denominator is set to 1.

For example:

```
Rational rationalOne = new Rational (1L, 2L); //this represents the fraction 1/2
rationalOne.add(2);                           //add takes a rational as an argument
```

The idea is, that it's getting implicit casted from 2 to 2/1.

Thanks for your help already

Comment: This isn't clear; why don't you just provide overloads for `add`?

Comment: i'd have to overload too many methods. my class implements add as a static method and as the non-static method in the example. same for sub, div, mul, shorten, expand.... would be a pain in the ass and a hell lot of work to implement all of them again, also an implicit cast would be easier to work with.

Comment: Alas, implicit conversions don't exist in Java.  You could consider writing a static helper method; then you could do `rationalOne.add(rat(2));`.

Comment: Then overload the constructor: public Rational(int integer) (or better, provide a named static factory method), and let the call call it: `r.add(new Rational(integer));`. The compiler can't magically generate code for you. You have to write it.

Comment: There are implicit casts, like from int to long.
My hope was, that there's a possibility to make your own implicit casts, by writing them in some sort of code.

Comment: No, that doesn't exist in Java.

Comment: Damn. But well, thank you for your efforts. Think i'll implement another constructor then.